# Al imprimir un arreglo de 10 espacios, se imprime otro numero demasiado grande

Tags: c++

No logro comprender como imprime ese onceavo numero.. Alguien con mas experiencia seria tan amable de verificarlo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;



int ordenarArreglo(int *arr)
{
int i, j, temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < (10 - 1); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<(10 - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j + 1 ]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
temp = 0;
i = 0;
j = 0;


    for(int z = 0;z <= 10;z++)
    {
        cout << " " << arr[z];
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Arreglo de diez numeros a modificar.
    int arr[10] = {15,1,3,4,8,9,7,6,7,4};

    cout << "El arreglo original es: ";

   for(int i=0;i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "El arreglo ordenado es: ";

    cout << ordenarArreglo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema en `<=`:

```
for(int z = 0;z <= 10;z++)
{
    cout << " " << arr[z];
}
```

Cambialo por `<`:

```
for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
{
    cout << " " << arr[z];
}
```

Simple despiste tuyo supongo. El resto de bucles están todos bien.

Y además:

```
int ordenarArreglo(int *arr);
```

El tipo de retorno es `int`, cuando en realidad no devuelves nada. Que devuelva `void`:

```
void ordenarArreglo(int *arr);
```

Y adicionalmente, también estás imprimiendo el valor de salida de la función (tu 11-avo valor, que en concreto, imprimirá basura, supongo; lo que no sé por qué no estás viendo 12 valores en vez de 11 teniendo en cuenta la vuelta extra del `<=`):

```
cout << ordenarArreglo(arr);
```

Sustituyelo por:

```
ordenarArreglo(arr);
```

Lo que me lleva a concluir que seguramente quieras realizar el bucle de impresión en el `main`. Código completo (con un par de cambios extra):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // para swap, o #include <utility> si usas C++11
// #include <stdlib.h> // No lo necesitas

using namespace std;

int ordenarArreglo(int *arr, int n) // Pasa el tamaño manualmente
{
    int i, j, temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) // Mejor preincrementos
        for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; ++j)
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
               std::swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1];
}

int main()
{
    //Arreglo de diez numeros a modificar.
    int arr[] = {15,1,3,4,8,9,7,6,7,4}; // El tamaño se calcula solo
    int n = sizeof(arr); // Aquí recuperas tu `10`. Así puedes añadir valores a `arr` con libertad.

    cout << "El arreglo original es: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << " " << arr[i];

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "El arreglo ordenado es: ";

    ordenarArreglo(arr, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << " " << arr[i];

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Si utilizas C++11, el `main` se simplifica:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {15,1,3,4,8,9,7,6,7,4};

    cout << "El arreglo original es: ";

    for(int v : arr)
        cout << " " << v; // `v` "itera" sobre los contenidos de `arr`.

    cout << endl << endl << "El arreglo ordenado es: ";

    ordenarArreglo(arr, sizeof(arr));

    for(int v : arr)
        cout << " " << v;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: De hecho ese igual que lo puse para ver si era eso, pero no, sale el onceavo numero aun sin el "<"

Comment: @Rubén Editado.

Comment: Removiendo el cout << ordenarArreglo(arr); y dejandolo como ordenarArreglo(arr); resolvió el problema, hermano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

#### Primer error

Tal como indica @Peregring-lk, en el ciclo con el que estás imprimiendo los valores, te estás saliendo del límite del arreglo, deberías cambiar:

```
for(int z = 0;z <= 10;z++)
```

Por

```
for(int z = 0;z < 10;z++)
```

#### Segundo error

La llamada a la función, la estás haciendo dentro de un cout, la tienes así:

```
cout << "El arreglo ordenado es: ";
```

Y deberías ser así

```
ordenarArreglo(arr);
```

Esto debe ser lo que está haciendo que se imprima un número grande, incluso después de que arreglas el primer error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema, como te han comentado, se encuentra en el último bucle de `ordenarArreglo`:

```
for(int z = 0;z <= 10;z++)
{
    cout << " " << arr[z];
}
```

En ese bucle estás iterando en el rango (0,10), cuando el rango válido es (0,9).

La solución más sencilla pasa por cambiar `<=` por `<`:

```
for(int z = 0;z < 10;z++)
{
    cout << " " << arr[z];
}
```

Sin embargo, el valor `10` se repite por doquier. Un buen hábito consiste en evitar que este tipo de valores se repliquen por el código como conejos. Imagínate que para hacer pruebas prefieres usar un valor bajo (por ejemplo 10) pero que luego en el entorno real tienes que usar un valor más grande (supone 500). ¿Vas a localizar todas las apariciones para reemplazarlas una a una? Espero que tu respuesta no sea afirmativa.

La solución a este problema pasa por usar variables constantes. Esta forma de trabajar proporciona dos grandes ventajas:

- Es muy sencillo cambiar el valor. Lo editas en un sitio y todo el código se adapta al nuevo valor.
- Los nombres suelen ser más descriptivos que los números. A la hora de encontrar errores no es lo mismo encontrarse con un literal e intentar deducir si dicho valor es correcto que encontrarse con una constante y, a partir de su nombre, saber si estás usando la constante correcta.

Ejemplo:

```
const int TamVector= 10;

int ordenarArreglo(int *arr)
{
  int i, j, temp = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < TamVector - 1; i++) // <<--- AQUI!!!
  {
    for(j = 0; j<(TamVector - i - 1); j++) // <<--- AQUI!!!
    {
      // ...
    }
  }

  // ...

  for(int z = 0;z < TamVector;z++) // <<--- AQUI!!!
  {
    cout << " " << arr[z];
  }
}

int main()
{
  //Arreglo de diez numeros a modificar.
  int arr[TamVector] = {15,1,3,4,8,9,7,6,7,4}; // <<--- AQUI!!!

  cout << "El arreglo original es: ";

  for(int i=0;i < TamVector; i++)
  {
    cout << " " << arr[i];
  }

  // ...
}
```

¿Y no sería mejor usar `#define`?

Lo cierto es que no ya que `#define` no dispone de un tipado fuerte, lo que puede provocar si no se tiene en cuenta ese pequeño pero crucial detalle.

Otro detalle tonto de tu código es la inicialización de `temp`, `i`, y `j` en mitad de `ordenarArreglo`. Ese código directamente sobra ya que esas variables no tienen uso. Aprovecho este párrafo para decirte también que esas variables deberías declararlas dentro del bucle correspondiente (como ya haces en otras secciones del código):

```
for(int i = 0; i < TamVector - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<(TamVector - i - 1); j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
        {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j + 1 ]= temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Es altamente recomendable reducir el ámbito de las variables al mínimo para evitar errores tontos al programar. Crear una variable `int` en cada iteración del bucle no tiene coste y, además, los compiladores pueden hacer maravillas al optimizar el código... mientras que alargar innecesariamente la vida de una variable puede dar lugar a problemas bastante complicados de encontrar ¿qué sucede si reutilizas una variable sin darte cuenta y asumes que está inicializada a un valor que no es el que realmente posee?

Otro detalle lo encontramos aquí:

```
temp = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[j+1];
arr[j + 1 ]= temp;
```

Que se puede sustituir tranquilamente por esto:

```
std::swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
```

Otro problema que tiene tu código lo encontramos aquí:

```
int ordenarArreglo(int *arr)
{
  // ...

  // ¿Y el return?
}
```

Si indicas que la función devuelve un entero necesariamente deberías poner un `return` en algún lado (preferiblemente al finalizar la función), sin embargo dicha instrucción brilla por su ausencia.

Esto genera un problema añadido y es que permite que la siguiente instrucción sea válida:

```
cout << ordenarArreglo(arr);
```

¿Realmente quieres imprimir un entero adicional después de mostrar el vector resultante por la pantalla? Imagino que no.

Resumiendo, la función debería tener la siguiente firma:

```
void ordenarArreglo(int *arr)
```

Y en la penúltima instrucción de tu programa sobra el `cout`:

```
ordenarArreglo(arr);
return 0; // También puedes poner return EXIT_SUCCESS; que queda más elegante
```